# Списки в прологе

Tags: prolog

Разбираюсь с прологом, пытаюсь реализовать удаление первого и последнего элемента из списка. Первый удаляется, а как изменить код, чтобы последний удалялся, никак не пойму.

```
domains
i=integer
list=i*
predicates
del(i,list,list)
clauses
del(1,[_|T],T):-!.
del(N,[_,Y|T],L):-N1=N-1,del(N1,[Y|T],L).
goal
del(1,[2,5,6,-5,7,8,11,16,23,4],L).
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, это правило не совсем верное.


    del(N,[_,Y|T],L):-N1=N-1,del(N1,[Y|T],L).

По ходу он удаляет первые N элементов (если честно сейчас даже проверить негде).
Если я не совсем упоролся, то должно быть как-то так

    del(N,[A|T],[A|L]):-N1=N-1,del(N1,T,L).

Comment: блин, и еще один вопросик: как последние два элемента удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо удалить и первый и последний, мне кажется, так должно сработать:

```
dellast([_],[]):-!
dellast([X|T],[X|Y]):-dellast(T,Y)
delfirstandlast([_,T],L):-dellast(T,L).
```

Comment: @rasmisha? спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1):

Удаление только первого:

```
delfirst([_|T],T). % И никакой рекурсии не нужно
```

Удаление последнего:

```
dellast([_],[]):-!.
dellast([X|T],[X|Y]):-dellast(T,Y).
```

Comment: @insolor, вот по отдельности это работает...а как это объединить, чтобы выполнялось сразу удаление первого и последнего? как-то в цель записать, не пойму(